# How to create a polyline on google map like the line showing in the image

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

[image]

I need to create a polyline that have shadow and elevation as well. Also i need to provide multiple colors to the line. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain on-topic problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) on the subject in the first place, including elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/), especially knowing that vast majority of newbies', usually elementary, questions has already been answered many times.

Comment: @Marcin: Thanks for you suggestion but i did some research and also use elementary search but i could not find any link related to that.

Answer (score 3):

At the present time polylines of Google Maps Android API don't support multiple colours. As I mentioned in the comment to pervious answer there is a feature request in Google issue tracker to implement gradient polylines in Maps Android API.

As a workaround you can implement your own GroundOverlay on top of the map that draws lines with different colours. Looking at similar questions at StackOverflow I figured out that some people have already implemented this functionality. For example you can have a look at this Github project that implements gradient polylines and polygons:

https://github.com/antoniocarlon/richmaps

I copied classes from this project and created a sample Google maps activity that shows a polyline similar to one you are looking for. The code snippet for my activity is the following

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private RichLayer richLayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        LatLng ny1 = new LatLng(40.711322,-74.007844);
        LatLng ny2 = new LatLng(40.782493,-73.965424);

        LatLng ny3 = new LatLng(40.75675,-73.98571);

        mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ny3, 12f));

        richLayer = new RichLayer.Builder(findViewById(R.id.map), mMap).zIndex(100).build();

        this.showPolylineAndShade(ny1, ny2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        // Refresh the RichLayer each time the camera changes
        richLayer.refresh();
    }

    private void showPolylineAndShade(LatLng p1, LatLng p2) {
        this.showCurvedLine(p1, p2, 0.1, Color.argb(30, 220,220,220), Color.argb(30, 192,192,192), Color.argb(30, 105,105,105),15);
        this.showCurvedLine(p1, p2, 0.3, Color.argb(255, 0,191,255), Color.argb(255, 26,188,156), Color.argb(255, 40,123,177),6);
    }

    private void showCurvedLine (LatLng p1, LatLng p2, double k, int basecolor, int color1, int color2,  int w) {
        //Calculate distance and heading between two points
        double d = SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(p1,p2);
        double h = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(p1, p2);

        //Midpoint position
        LatLng p = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p1, d*0.5, h);

        //Apply some mathematics to calculate position of the circle center
        double x = (1-k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);
        double r = (1+k*k)*d*0.5/(2*k);

        LatLng c = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(p, x, h + 90.0);

        //Calculate heading between circle center and two points
        double h1 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p1);
        double h2 = SphericalUtil.computeHeading(c, p2);

        //Calculate positions of points on circle border and add them to polyline options
        int numpoints = 1000;
        double step = (h2 -h1) / numpoints;

        RichPolylineOptions polylineOpts = new RichPolylineOptions(null)
                .zIndex(100) // zIndex represents the position of the polyline on the RichLayer
                .strokeWidth(w)
                .strokeColor(basecolor)
                .linearGradient(false);

        Point fromScreenPoint = null;
        Point toScreenPoint = null;
        int[] colors = new int[]{color1, color2};
        Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();

        for (int i=0; i < numpoints; i++) {
            LatLng pi = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(c, r, h1 + i * step);
            RichPoint rp = new RichPoint(pi);
            polylineOpts.add(rp);
            if (i == 0) {
                fromScreenPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(rp.getPosition());
            }
            if (i == numpoints -1) {
                toScreenPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(rp.getPosition());
            }
        }

        if (fromScreenPoint!=null && toScreenPoint!=null) {
            int fromX = fromScreenPoint.x ;
            int fromY = fromScreenPoint.y;
            int toX = toScreenPoint.x;
            int toY = toScreenPoint.y;

            polylineOpts.strokeShader(new LinearGradient(fromX, fromY, toX, toY,
                    colors, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP));
        }

        RichPolyline polyline = polylineOpts.build();
        richLayer.addShape(polyline);
    }
}
```

This code will create a polyline as shown in the following screentshot

[image]

You can find and download a sample project at Github

https://github.com/xomena-so/so45648311

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Seems there is no "standard" methods to do it in Android Google Maps API, but You always can do it manually with custom View placed over map fragment. Something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    />

    <your.custom.component.Name
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can get coords of curve from map and draw it on Your  custom view canvas with transparency.

Comment: I can only add that in Google issue tracker you can find a feature request to add gradient polylines in Google Maps Android API: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828754. You can star this feature request to add your vote.